# Simulating baseline for Q learning research

Tags: r

Im trying to built a function for my Q learning research. It suppose to receive number of trails and repeat probability and simulate data of choosing between 2 actions (0,1) each step, according to the repeat probability. (baseline so no learning according to reward, only switching between actions according to given prob).

```
  sim.block = function(Ntrl, repeat_p){ 
  for (i in 2:Ntrl){
    action = sample(x = c(0,1), size = Ntrl, replace=T)
   last.action <- action[i-1] # the number in the previous step
  
  if(last.action==0){
    action[i] <- sample(x = c(0,1), size = 1, prob = c(repeat_p,1-repeat_p))
  } else {
    action[i] <- sample(x = c(0,1), size = 1, prob = c(1-repeat_p,repeat_p))
  }}
    return (data.frame(action))
    }
```

When i test the functions with extreme repeat probability i dont get what i expect.
For example, when i insert  `sim.block(400,0.000000001)`  i expcect to get no repeat at all but its not the case. the same for 0.999999999, i expect to get only repeat but i get random list of 1s and 0s.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is just a small error regarding the creation of the sample. This should be *outside* of the loop, e.g.:

```
set.seed(1)
action = sample(x = c(0,1), size = Ntrl, replace=T)
for (i in 2:Ntrl){
  last.action <- action[i-1] # the number in the previous step
  #if (i == 4) break
  if(last.action==0){
    action[i] <- sample(x = c(0,1), size = 1, prob = c(repeat_p,1-repeat_p))
  } else {
    action[i] <- sample(x = c(0,1), size = 1, prob = c(1-repeat_p,repeat_p))
  }}
```

the result for your example of Ntrl=400 and repeat_p is than:

```
> action
  [1] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
 [73] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
[145] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
[217] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
[289] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
[361] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

Comment: Works great! Can you explain the logic behind it?

Comment: Well, when you put the creation of the vector inside the loop, every iteration step a new vector (with random 0, 1, order) is created. You are iterating inside the vector in the same time over the slots to proof if repetition appears. So just imagine the last step of your loop: First a completely new vector with 0 and 1 is created (repetition occurs), 2. only the last entry is checked for repetition and changed by probability. So, the other n-1 entries are staying the same, disregarding any probability.